# Clarification about Lucid Virtu

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, intel-graphics

Finally I've solved my problem. I have installed 3 monitors via DVI/HDMI with one dedicated Nvidia graphics card. I have now my iGPU of the i5-2500k in use for the third monitor. I use a Z68 (P8Z68-V) board along with a Nvidia GTX 570. The only thing I've had to enable was this very weirdly named 4th option:
[image]

What confuses me is that I've thought **Lucid Virtu** is activated on the *software side*. Though my three monitors work perfectly fine without any software installed.

So what benefits would I get through installing the Lucid Virtu software. And what drawbacks would I get if I don't?

What I currently think is that just for example full screen gaming would be possible on all three screens, even on the one plugged into the motherboard, if I installed the Lucid Virtu software. If I would not install the software, am I right that gaming would not be possible on the screen plugged into the MB?

Don't get me wrong. I only want to play on one screen at a time. Three monitors are only used for *working*. I'm just interested in understanding this concept.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. Your question drops us in the middle of your thought process. Rewrite it to clearly explain what your computer is, what your OS is, what the screenshot is, where you enabled what, and what your actual question is.

Comment: @terdon: My question is what is the benefit of installing the Lucid Virtu software is, even though three monitors work without it. As single Nvidia GPUs do not support 3 monitors, there isn't any more to clarify. I enabled this BIOS option to run the third one (without the **4th** option enabled it does not work). What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the 'actual' question here:

> So what benefits would I get through installing the Lucid Virtu
> software. And what drawbacks would I get if I don't?

I think the confusion in the rest of your question is about multi-monitor support. Virtu is not about multi-monitor support it's used to direct graphics task to the appropriate GPU (either an IGP or dedicated card).

From their [product page](http://lucidlogix.com/product-virtu-gpu.html):

> With Virtu software, next-generation PCs with 2nd Generation Intel®
> Core™ processor platforms will dynamically balance the advanced
> power-efficient, built-in media features of Intel Core processor
> graphics with the high-end, DirectX 11 3D, anti-aliasing and
> performance features of discrete GPUs, while significantly reducing
> the power drain of traditional entertainment desktops. Ultimately, the
> consumer is assured optimal simultaneous performance in 3D gaming and
> video functions like transcoding and HD playback without the need to
> swap video cable connections between GPUs.

Virtu will have the IGP handle tasks like normal Windows use and video transcoding while directing gaming tasks (like DirectX calls) to a dedicated card. This is to save on power and cooling while not gaming. It also allows use [Intel QuickSync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video) in Sandy Bridge and higher CPUs while still having a powerful gaming card.

again from the same page:

> **How Virtu GPU Virtualization Works**
>
> Lucid Virtu software is able to assign tasks in real time to the best available graphics resource
> based on power, performance and features considerations, with no need
> for additional hardware. If high end graphics power is needed for
> applications like DirectX 11, high-resolution 3D gaming, the system
> will assign the job to the discrete GPU. If not, the discrete GPU
> automatically goes into idle mode, while heat drops, fan speed slows
> down and GPU utilization goes down to zero, resulting in a green,
> power-efficient, long-lasting system.

The only drawbacks that I know would be:

- The overhead of the software to redirect calls (which is minimal from what I understand)
- Any configuration hassle from getting it set up
- Having to connect thru the IGP which may not support more than 2 monitors.

Comment: So it does not matter where the monitor(s) is plugged in? I'm not the hardware guy, sorry.

Comment: Added some more info. I believe you need to connect thru the IGP which may limit the number of monitors you can run (a lot of motherboards only support dual monitors).

Comment: @ebeeb: It only matters where the monitors are plugged in if you're trying to save power. Obviously, the graphics card can't be powered down if a monitor is connected to it.